# When I plug in a dimmable lamp on the other side of the house, a GFCI outlet in my kitchen starts humming. What gives?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, gfci, lamp

The GFCI outlet in the kitchen ONLY buzzes when the following two conditions are met:

(1) Microwave is plugged in
(2) Dimmable lamp on other side of house is turned on

Any idea what could be causing this?  Never had any issues with this outlet until relocating the lamp to a new outlet and turning it out, which leads me to believe the issue is either with the lamp, or with the outlet that the lamp is plugged into.

I have read all other questions pertaining to GFCI issues but cannot find any that seem to pertain to this strange issue.

Thank you for any assistance in this matter!

Comment: Is either the dimmable lamp or the microwave plugged into an outlet on the same circuit as the GFCI, or the GFCI itself?

Comment: Does the "test" button cause the GFI to trip?  Is the microwave plugged into the GFI circuit?  Does the microwave have to be "on" (that is, microwaving something)?

Comment: When you test trip the GFI does the lamp on the other outlet lose power?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel The lamp is in fact a dimmable lamp, and the microwave is plugged into the GFCI outlet.

Comment: @wallyk Test button does not trip GFCI.  Microwave is plugged into GFCI outlet.  Microwave does not have to be actively Microwaving anything

Comment: @MichaelKaras No.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Sorry - misread your comment, and it won't let me edit it for some reason.

To actually answer your question - the Microwave is plugged into a GFCI outlet.  The lamp is not.

Comment: @wallyk  I apologize - I provided the wrong information.  The test button does in fact trip the circuit.  I was thinking of the reset button in my previous reply (I even looked at it and checked, and for some reason, my brain switched the two in my head when I replied)

Comment: Did you ever stop the buzzing or learn more information about what was happening? I'm having buzzing in several GFI's lately.

Answer (score 2):

Since the GFI's *test* button does not make it trip, the GFI should be replaced pronto.  Until that can be done, unplug everything from it and from downstream outlets.

The *test* button is not an accessory feature.  It uses simple electronics to produce a slightly unbalanced current so as to directly test the protection logic.  If that doesn't work, the protective circuitry has failed.  That, plus any buzzing (especially under bizarre circumstances) is a screaming cry to fix it.

Comment: I am terribly sorry - I provided the wrong information.  The TEST button does in fact make the outlet trip.  I was for some reason thinking you were talking about the top button (reset button).